# Ag-grid and Angular2 using angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ag-grid

I'm trying to run ag-grid with angular2, the examples in the ag-grid site are using SystemJS as builder, and the new angular-cli uses webpack.

Below I will put the way I'm run, but I'm not using ag-grid-ng2. I don't know where to reference the ag-grid-ng2 in angular-cli.json.

I wanted to use something like this step-by-step:

I'm using:

- Node: 6.9.2
- NPM: 4.0.5
- Typescript: 2.1.4
- Angular CLI: 1.0.0-beta.22-1
- Ag-Grid: 7.0.2

I used the following commands to start the project, and didn't change anything, except what will be described below:

```
ng new MyProject
cd MyProject
npm install --save ag-grid
npm install --save ag-grid-ng2
```

Then I edited the file 'angular-cli.json':

```
"styles": [
  "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
  "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/theme-blue.css",
  "styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/ag-grid.js"
],
```

File: app.component.html

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>

<div  id="grid-test"
      style="height: 250px;" 
      class="ag-blue">
</div>
```

File: app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Grid, GridOptions } from "ag-grid/main";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'app works!';
  gridOptions: GridOptions;

  constructor() {   
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};
    this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [];
    this.gridOptions.columnDefs.push({ headerName: 'name', field: 'name' });

    var el = document.querySelector('#grid-test');
    new Grid(<HTMLDivElement>el, this.gridOptions);

    let data: any[] = [];
    data.push({name: 'Name 1'});
    data.push({name: 'Name 2'});
    data.push({name: 'Name 3'});
    this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(data);
  }

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I am learning this stuff too, and from what I understand it has something to do with how Angular-Cli is using a non-extendable webpack config.  There are a lot of complaints right now about the fact you cant add additional controls beyond angular2/material.

I have a strong feeling that there is a file within the node_modules/angular-cli/tasks folder that will give us what we want, but I haven't found it yet

Comment: I get the grid to display, but it is messed up. All of the column data display on top of each other and the table keeps infinitely expanding every half-second or so, bit by bit. This may cause me to ditch angular-cli and go with a webpack seed. This library is very important to my project.

Comment: Has anyone come up with a solution for this one?  I built a few modules for a new App using the Angular website as my guide, and decided to bring it over to Angular-cli last week.  Ag-grid is used heavily throughout my modules.  Anyway, finally go everything working, but ran into the same issues as @KentJohnson describes.  Slow rendering, data loading as a mess.  I am curious if anyone has a solution (even with Webpack seed) they want to share?

Answer (score 0):

When using Angular-CLI for Ag-Grid rather than using `ag-grid-ng2`, I would suggest you use `ag-grid-angular`. Hope these references would help:

- [Ag Grid - Building with Angular CLI](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-angular-angularcli/#gsc.tab=0)
- [Ag Grid Angular Example](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid-angular-example/tree/master/angular-cli)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.